# How to add list items to this angular-carousel code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

We are trying to make a supermarket game application with angular.js. And part of the app is when the user scrolls to the left and to the right it changes aisles. We need each aisle to have three shelves with items on them. We found this angular carousel for the scrolling. But we need a way to have our objects show up in the view on each slide. Each slide is a `li` tag. Inside the ngRepeat `ul` for the carousel we tried putting our `li`'s for the items to be placed on the shelves, but this didn't come up with the result we were looking for.

This is where we got the code for the carousel:
[angular-carousel GitHub](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel)

This is our game on Plunker:
[Plunker | Supermarket Game](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfXdh6yqBkEkiNvTOq4N?p=preview)

Comment: you really need to learn to scale your issues down to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make it less complex.